# lightswitch html client for visual studio 2010

Tags: html, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am evaluating this product under VS2010 and I see that I only have the possibility to use LS as silverlight or desktop application.

What do I need to do in order to run it as HTML app?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*LS 2011 (V1)* didn't have an **HTML client**, only a **Silverlight client**. The HTML Client was introduced with *LS 2012 (V2)* for VS 2012.

Comment: I'm curious on an update concerning the HTML client. Does this only produce mobile apps? Any way of using VS Lightswitch to build a complete web app that runs on a browser?

Comment: You can run HTML Client apps in a normal tablet/desktop browser, they don't *have* to be run on a mobile device.